# Two for loop in one line

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I know I can use the following syntax for loop in one line:

```
[print(x) for x in range(10)]
```

How can I use this syntax to combine two loops in one line?

Comment: **never do this**. You are talking about a *list comprehension*, which **is not** a single-line for-loop. Using list comprehension a for side effects is bad, don't do it. List comprehension are for mapping/filtering operations on iterables to *create a list*

Comment: This is not my answer

Comment: Yes, it answers everything about your question. Read the accepted answer, it is quite extensive

Answer (score 1):

You can use code something like below. It allows iterating by an array of arrays.

```
x = [[2,5,6],[3,5,1]]
result = [[value[i] for value in x] for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[(i, j) for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]` for instance or `[[i for in range(j)] for j in range(10)]` and you can combine those ideas in any way you want